# Execute first part of code as root, second part as other user

Tags: python, bash, root, popen

I am having issues getting some code to work. I have some interactive program that has two parts to execute:

1 - It has to make sure that some directories have proper permissions. Basically a simple `chown`. This part needs to be executed as root per system requirements.

2 - It has to execute some code as other user that user root can normally `su` into without any password.

I have been trying to use subprocess.Popen() without much luck, does anyone have any idea of how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: sudo -u user command

Comment: If the interactive program is an externally executed program, i.e. not part of your Python code? Is there just one program? Does it need to acquire and relinquish root permissions at different times, or does it just need root permissions once only at the start?

Comment: The interactive program is written in python, and ideally would be part of the same python script, but I could live with a wrapper script. This interactive script doesn't need to be root, I just need these permissions at the beginning to perform a chown

Comment: Do you have the password? Then you could wrap it in expect and start your python application with a bash script.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. I created a launcher in bash and used su to launch the python as the other user

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help (*as 'bash' instructions*).

(*everything after **#**, in the code, is my comments*)

Divide the code into two parts - for 'root' (*superuser*) and $USER (*other users*).
Check IF it's **not** a 'root'; THEN do something...

```sh
if [ $(whoami) != 'root' ]; then
  # do some $USER instructions...
```

> `$(...)` *- wrapper to run commands*
> [`whoami`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whoami.1.html) *- print effective userid*

ELSE (*if it's 'root'*) do some superuser instructions...

```sh
else
  # do some 'root' instructions
fi # end of 'IF' condition
```

In the $USER (*`$(whoami) != 'root'`*) section, when needed, run this script with 'root' privileges. And you can pass an argument (*such as 'DO_CHOWN'*) as a call for a specific action:

```sh
sudo -s "$0" DO_CHOWN
```

> [`sudo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html) *- run command as superuser (by default)*
>      *`-s` - will save the current script path*
> `$0` *- the current script, with a path*
> `DO_CHOWN` *- any argument (name doesn't matter) which we pass to get*

After using the `sudo`, you will be prompted for the password to access.
If you don't want to enter the password constantly.
You can use something like this:

```sh
echo 'yourpassword' | sudo -Ss "$0" DO_CHOWN
```

> [`echo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) *- outputs the data*
> `|` *- (pipe) redirects the output, in this case, from `echo` to the `sudo`*
> `-S` *- will write output from the "echo" into the prompt*

In the 'root' (*else*) section, we need to get the argument (*'DO_CHOWN'*) that we passed.
Something like that:

```sh
if [[ $@ =~ 'DO_CHOWN' ]]; then
  # do chown instructions...
  exit
fi
```

> `$@` *- all arguments passed to the script*
> `=~` *- looks for a match to the value specified on the right*
> [`exit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) *- terminate the process*

The final code:

```sh
# IF not 'root'
if [ $(whoami) != 'root' ]; then
  echo 'User:' $(whoami) # show current username
  echo 'Path:' $(pwd) # show current directory of the script
  sudo -s "$0" DO_CHOWN # send 'DO_CHOWN' argument as a call for a specific action
  # THEN enter your password, OR:
  # echo 'yourpassword' | sudo -Ss "$0" DO_CHOWN # to not enter the password manually
  echo "Continue as $(whoami)..."
# IF 'root'
else
  echo 'User:' $(whoami)
  echo 'Path:' $(pwd)
  # IF get the 'DO_CHOWN' argument
  if [[ $@ =~ 'DO_CHOWN' ]]; then
    echo 'do chown instructions...'
    exit
  fi
fi
```

Console output:

```console
User: user_name
Path: /home/user_name
[sudo] password for user_name:
User: root
Path: /home/user_name
do chown instructions...
Continue as user_name...
```

Like. <s>Subscribe.</s> Comment

Comment: Please provide a little explanation; code-only answers, even when correct, don't do much to help the OP figure out what they did wrong.

Comment: The code is pretty well commented, and I am able to understand it, though I agree that some written explanation would be great for someone not familiar with bash

Comment: @SuperStar, Described as I could 

Comment: @JavierRieraChirivella Ok. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a bash script that has to be executed as root, so it first performs the chown and then executes the python bit. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R user:user /path/to/change
su -c 'python3 -c "first python step; second python step"' user
```

I make use of the -c options of both su and python3 to indicate which commands to execute and which user to execute them as.